# How to configure ctags to work with CSS, SCSS, HTML?

Tags: vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I've already read a lot of blog posts and answers on stackoverflow, but it seems I do something wrong, because I still have the `E388: Couldn't find definition` error. What I did:

- Download ctags from here http://ctags.sourceforge.net/
- Install it by: `./configure && make install`
- Set `tags+=tags;$HOME` in my `.vimrc` file
- Add some lines into `~/.ctags` (see below)
- Do `ctags -R .` in the project root and get some warnings (see below)
- Check classes by `:tag .<C-D>` which gives me a big list of classes (that pleases)

The warnings:

```
ctags: Warning: regcomp ([A-Za-z0-9._$]+)[ t]*[:=][ t]*{: Unmatched \{
ctags: Warning: regcomp ([A-Za-z0-9._$()]+)[ t]*[:=][ t]*function[ t]*(: Unmatched ( or \(
ctags: Warning: regcomp ([A-Za-z0-9._$]+)[ t]*[:=][ t]*[: Invalid regular expression
ctags: Warning: cannot open source file "static/img/touch/packages" : No such file or directory
```

My `~/.ctags` file looks as follows:

```
--exclude=*.min.js
--exclude=*.min.css
--exclude=*.map
--exclude=.backup
--exclude=.sass-cache
--exclude=vendors
--exclude=.git

--langdef=css
--langmap=css:.css
--langmap=css:+.sass
--langmap=css:+.styl
--langmap=css:+.less
--regex-css=/^[ \t]*\.([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/.\1/c,class,classes/
--regex-css=/^[ \t]*#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/#\1/i,id,ids/
--regex-css=/^[ \t]*(([A-Za-z0-9_-]+[ \t\n,]+)+)\{/\1/t,tag,tags/
--regex-css=/^[ \t]*@media\s+([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/m,media,medias/

--langdef=scss
--langmap=scss:.scss
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]*@mixin ([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/m,mixin,mixins/
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]*\$([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/v,variable,variables/
--regex-scss=/^([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)*(\.[A-Za-z0-9_-]+) *[,{]/\2/c,class,classes/
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9_-]+) *[,{]/\1/c,class,classes/
--regex-scss=/^(.*)*\#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+) *[,{]/\2/i,id,ids/
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]*#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/i,id,ids/
--regex-scss=/(^([A-Za-z0-9_-])*([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)) *[,|\{]/\1/t,tag,tags/
--regex-scss=/(^([^\/\/])*)[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)) *[,|\{]/\3/t,tag,tags/
--regex-scss=/(^(.*, *)([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)) *[,|\{]/\3/t,tag,tags/
--regex-scss=/(^[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)) *[,|\{]/\1/t,tag,tags/
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]*@media\s+([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/d,media,media/

--regex-html=/id="([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)"/\1/i,id,ids/
--regex-html=/class="([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)"/\1/c,class,classes/

--langdef=js
--langmap=js:.js
--regex-js=/([A-Za-z0-9._$]+)[ t]*[:=][ t]*{/1/,object/
--regex-js=/([A-Za-z0-9._$()]+)[ t]*[:=][ t]*function[ t]*(/1/,function/
--regex-js=/function[ t]+([A-Za-z0-9._$]+)[ t]*(([^)]))/1/,function/
--regex-js=/([A-Za-z0-9._$]+)[ t]*[:=][ t]*[/1/,array/
--regex-js=/([^= ]+)[ t]*=[ t]*[^"]'[^']*/1/,string/
--regex-js=/([^= ]+)[ t]*=[ t]*[^']"[^"]*/1/,string/
```

Project structure:

[image]

Wherever (`static/index.html`, `static/css/main.scss` or `static/css/components/set.scss`) I try to "jump to definition" using `]^D` I always get `E388: Couldn't find definition`. What happens?

**UPDATE**

`<C-]>` pressed at the beginning of `_col-2` name:

- in case of `<div class="_col-2">..` gives `E426: Tag not found: _col`. It looks like vim doesn't detect classname correctly.
- in case of `.class { @extend ._col-2; }` gives the same.

As suggest @romainl, after adding `set iskeyword+=-` in `.vimrc` to dash be a part of the keyword, pressing on `<div class="_col-2">..` throws me at the beginning of the line.

Comment: On a side note: you should consider using the less exuberant but maintained [universal ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags) instead.

Comment: I've already see it, but there is no good readme (like "hey, that's reimplementation!" and that all :)), so I skip it. What the benefits using universal ctags over "classic" one?

Comment: The "classic" `ctags` from 1970's is long dead.  Exuberant `ctags` is not that "classic" and not so long dead, but it's still dead.  Universal `ctags` is a fork of Exuberant `ctags` that is actively maintained.  Among other things, it has fixed some long-standing problems in Exuberant `ctags`, and it added support for more languages.  The only regression as far as I can tell is the occasional use of [Engrish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engrish) in the various docs. :)

Comment: Good explanation)) By the way, is there any information listing the supported languages? I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About `E426: Tag not found: txal-center`…

These lines in your `.ctags` will index `.foo-bar` — **with the leading dot** — in `*.scss` files:

```
--regex-scss=/^([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)*(\.[A-Za-z0-9_-]+) *[,{]/\2/c,class,classes/
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9_-]+) *[,{]/\1/c,class,classes/
```

When you press `<C-]>` over a class name in an HTML document, Vim will look for that exact class name, say `foo-bar`, but it won't find it because you only have `.foo-bar` in your `tags` file. That's because Vim does "whole-word" search by default.

The solution to this specific problem is to leave the dot out of the tag:

```
--regex-scss=/^([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)*\.([A-Za-z0-9_-]+) *[,{]/\2/c,class,classes/
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]+\.([A-Za-z0-9_-]+) *[,{]/\1/c,class,classes/
```

Comment: Hm..I changed it as you suggest, delete old `ctags` file, generate it again `ctags -R .` and check it by `:tag ^D`. However the dots have remained. Here are a lot of classes starting with dot. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `]<C-D>` motion is for *macro definitions*, powered by Vim's internal file search and the `'define'` option. It doesn't use the tags database, and is mostly for C / C++ macros. What you want is the equivalent to the `:tag` command (which apparently does work for you). This is `<C-]>` (or `<C-LeftMouse>`); you'll find it directly under `:help :tag`.

Comment: Unfortunately, but when I press <C-]> nothing happens, I just get the message at the bottom of screen: `tag 1 of 3 or more`.

Comment: It doesn't properly detect class name, eg when I press ^] on `<div class="_col-3" ...` (cursor on _) - I get the error `E426: Tag not found: _col`

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov, that's because `-` is not part of the ìskeyword` option. You can add it with `:set iskeyword+=-`. This will be useful in both HTML and CSS/LESS/SASS/SCSS files.

Comment: Now, when I press on `_col-3` it just throw me at the beginning of the line. Pressing on `_row` still gives the same `tag 1 of 3 or more`.

Comment: @romainl, I've added it already (at my previous comment too). It strange, but despite of running explicitly `:tag .txal-center` moves me to the right place, pressing `^]` at the same class but in HTML gives error: `E426: Tag not found: txal-center`. It look like vim missing automatic addition of the dot before the class name..

Answer (score 0):

It seems I find the solution, thanks to @romainl and @IngoKarkat for the tip with excluding dots from regexp. So here are the steps if you haven't tried [Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) with HTML, CSS, SCSS.

- Download the [latest version](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) and extract
- Go into the extracted folder and run:`./configure && make && sudo make install`. Now check if ctags installed correctly by running `ctags --help`
- Create `~/.ctags` file and place the code there (see below)
- Add the line `set tags+=tags;$HOME` into your `~/.vimrc`, then run `:so ~/.vimrc` to update the options. `tags+=tags;$HOME` means search `tags` file recursively from current folder up to your home directory. If your prefer another
- Go into your project folder and run `ctags -R .`. It creates `ctags` file which is index(database) of the found definitions.
- Now go to vim `vim .` and check if tags are available by `:tag ^D` (press CTRL-D)
- Now you can list tags, go to definition, back to previous place by `b]`, `CTRL-]`, `CTRL-T` accordingly.
- (optionally) You can run `ctags -R -f .tags` to generate hidden file instead of the default `tags` name. Don't forget to change the `set tags+=tags;$HOME` to `set tags+=.tags;$HOME`
- (optionally) Add `nmap <leader><leader> :!ctags -R -f .tags<CR>` to .vimrc if you want to update the index faster. Track you parent directory when you do it by `:pwd` in order not to pollute each project folder with `tags` files.

`~/.ctags` content:

```
--exclude=*.min.js
--exclude=*.min.css
--exclude=*.map
--exclude=.backup
--exclude=.sass-cache
--exclude=vendors
--exclude=.git

--langdef=css
--langmap=css:.css
--langmap=css:+.styl
--langmap=css:+.less
--regex-css=/^[ \t]*\.([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/c,class,classes/
--regex-css=/^[ \t]*#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/i,id,ids/
--regex-css=/^[ \t]*(([A-Za-z0-9_-]+[ \t\n,]+)+)\{/\1/t,tag,tags/
--regex-css=/^[ \t]*@media\s+([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/m,media,medias/

--langdef=scss
--langmap=scss:.sass
--langmap=scss:+.scss
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]*@mixin ([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/m,mixin,mixins/
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]*@function ([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/f,function,functions/
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]*\$([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/v,variable,variables/
--regex-scss=/^([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)*\.([A-Za-z0-9_-]+) *[,{]/\2/c,class,classes/
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]+\.([A-Za-z0-9_-]+) *[,{]/\1/c,class,classes/
--regex-scss=/^(.*)*\#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+) *[,{]/\2/i,id,ids/
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]*#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/i,id,ids/
--regex-scss=/(^([A-Za-z0-9_-])*([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)) *[,|\{]/\1/t,tag,tags/
--regex-scss=/(^([^\/\/])*)[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)) *[,|\{]/\3/t,tag,tags/
--regex-scss=/(^(.*, *)([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)) *[,|\{]/\3/t,tag,tags/
--regex-scss=/(^[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)) *[,|\{]/\1/t,tag,tags/
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]*@media\s+([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/d,media,media/
```